# Se puede hacer doble find en mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo esa coleccion de un chat donde userrecived es el que recive el mensaje y usersend el que lo envia, cuestion que quiero hacer una busqueda doble que cumpla con pedido

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbd6463ab382a316bf353fb"),
    "mensaje" : "Hola",
    "userrecived" : "1111111111",
    "usersend" : "2222222222",
    "fecha" : ISODate("2020-11-24T19:52:00.992Z")
}
```

Ahora quiero hacer una consulta que coincida con los campos

```
        "userrecived" : "1111111111",
        "usersend" : "2222222222",
```

Esto con un simple find lo se hacer, pero quiero que tambien me busque asi

```
 "userrecived" : "2222222222",
    "usersend" : "1111111111",
```

Y después hacer un sort según la fecha, si se pudiera hacer y que me devuelva en un json me resolvería muchos problemas
intente hacer algo asi pero no se puede

```
db.getCollection('mensajes').find( { $or: [ 
{{ "userrecived": "111111111" }, {"usersend" : "222222222"}}
,
{{"userrecived" : "222222222"},{"usersend" : "11111111111"}} 
    ]})
```

Y si no se puede, también me serviría unir dos consultas por separado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El siguiente código debe permitirte buscar los documentos de la colección `mensajes` que coincidan con `userrecived: '111111111', usersend: '222222222'` y `userrecived: '222222222', usersend: '11111111111'`.

```javascript
db.getCollection('mensajes').find({
  $or: [
    { userrecived: '111111111', usersend: '222222222' },
    { userrecived: '222222222', usersend: '11111111111' }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Me sirvio muchas gracias!